# $.ajax возвращает null

Tags: php, javascript

Пытаюсь получить ответ от сервера, приходит Null
Js

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/php/test.php", // куда отправляем
    type: "post", // метод передачи
    dataType: "json", // тип передачи данных
    data: { // что отправляем
        "count":    count,
    },
    // после получения ответа сервера
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.rez)
    }
});
```

php

```
$html = '
<div class="js-gallery-advanced">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="block-content-new1">
                <div class="push">
                    <em class="pull-right">30 просмотров</em>
                    <span class="text-primary font-w600">Продам</span>
                </div>
                <div class="push-10">
                    <div class="h4 font-w600 text-success pull-right push-10-l">990 Руб</div>
                    <a class="h4" href="frontend_ecom_product.html">Стартер и колонк</a> <small class="text-primary">Торг</small>
                </div>
                <p class="text-muted">Продам почти новый стартер и колонки, без торга</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
';

$options=array(
"rez"=>$html,
 );

echo json_encode($options);
```

Если в переменно $html убрать все дивы кроме первого, то ответ приходит

```
$html = '
<div class="js-gallery-advanced">
</div>
';
```

Comment: Ваш код работает(jquery 3). Смотрите ошибки браузера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В хроме(также как и в firefox) можно правой кнопкой открыть пункт Просмотреть код(инспектировать елемент)  и дале в открывшемся окне выбрать сеть, где будут все запросы с их кодами и ответами. Также там можно просмотреть и аякс запросы которые вы отправляете со всей необходимой информацией.

Бывает что в одном браузере может не работать(сегодня сам с такой проблемой столкнулся) а в другом всё будет нормально. Тут как вариант - чистить кеш и перезапускать браузер.

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка было в кодировке файла .php